# Garbage characters added after re.sub()?

Tags: python, regex

Why the following regular expression returns garbage !!

```
 expr = 'a + b'
 expr2 = re.sub(r'\w', 'probs["\1"]', expr)
```

> probs[""] + probs[""]

[image: this is how it looks]

or:

> probs["\x01"] + probs["\x01"]

---

desired output :

> probs["a"] + probs["b"]

---

Stupid me I forgot the brackets :

```
   expr2 = re.sub(r'(\w)', r'probs["\1"]', expr)
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

`\1` is being interpreted as the character with ascii value 1.  You probably want to add an r to make it a raw string, or use `\\1` in the string.

Comment: `\\1` does not work.

Comment: Well, the original match is also not capturing anything, so that makes sense